# Cant group by column (Doctrine 2 + Mysql 5.7)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying to group on users and path and limit 1 path per user based on created column. Below are my results, the problem is that user_id(1) is found twice since the path is different

RESULT

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "lastname": "Short",
    "firstname": "Admin",
    **"path": "/dashboard"**
},
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "lastname": "Short",
    "firstname": "Admin",
    **"path": "/works"**
},
{
    "user_id": 2,
    "lastname": "Administrator",
    "firstname": "John",
    "path": "/dashboard"
}
```

ENTITIES

```
user => | id | firstname | lastname | profile_image | created

beat => | id | user_id(rel) | created | path
```

QueryBuilder (Symfony)

```
        return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('
            u.id as user_id,
            u.lastname,
            u.firstname,
            u.profile_image,
            b.path
        ')
        ->join('b.user', 'u')
        ->groupBy('u.id, b.path')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch each user only once, using `DISTINCT(u.id) AS user_id` should do the trick. If you want to stick to dql `->select('u.id as user_id)->distinct()`